# How to have a sum of cells not exceed another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

Cell A23 get's its value from cells A19:A22. 
Cell A23 cannot be higher than the number already in cell H2.

What formula would I use in data validation to accomplish this?

Comment: What do yo mean by data validation? Error message when a value entered would cause sum to be too large?

Comment: I am using data validation so I get a warning message to appear. I tried entering =SUM(A19:A22)<H2 into cell A23, however it does not stop me when adding numbers into the sum'd amount of what causes A23 to be highter than H2.

Comment: FYI, data validation to some people mean using the data validation tool in excel. Go to the data tab -> data tools...

Comment: Nora: Brevity is great, but this question could use a bit more detail.  Are you saying that cell `A23` contains the formula ```=SUM(A19:A22)```?  Then ***say so**, in the question.*  Are you saying that you want to validate user data input in cells `A19:A22`?  So, for example, if `A19=1`, `A20=20`, `A21=16` and `H2=42`, then`A22` must be ≤ `5`?  Then ***say so**.*

Comment: A23 contains the sum of A19:A22. My apologies Scott, I am new at excel.

Comment: It's nothing to do with being "new at Excel". It's not about facility with Excel. It's about writing a problem statement. I'd suggest taking @Scott's advice and [edit] your question to include more specific information about your setup and requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in Data Validation in A19:A22:

```
=SUM($A$19:$A$22)<=H2
```

Comment: For which cell this rule need to be entered?

Comment: Cell A23 is the location

Comment: @Nora the data validation should be applied to the data set and not the sum output.